# If $Tx\perp b$ for all $x$ with $x\perp b\in B$, does it follow $T\overline{\text{span}B}^\perp\perp\overline{\text{span}B}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $T\in\mathfrak L(H)$, $B\subseteq H$ with $$Tx\perp b\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H\text{ and }b\in B\text{ with }x\perp b\tag1$$ and $U:=\overline{\operatorname{span}B}$.

> Are we able to conclude $TU^\perp\subseteq U^\perp$?

From $(1)$ we deduce that $$TB^\perp\perp B\tag2;$$ i.e. $$TB^\perp\subseteq B^\perp.\tag3$$ By (conjugate-)linearity of the inner product, we easily conclude $$TB^\perp\perp\operatorname{span}B\tag4$$ and from continuity of the inner product, we obtain $$TB^\perp\perp U\tag5.$$ Can we somehow utilize linearity and continuity of $T$ to deal with the left-hand side of $(5)$ in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that $TU^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$. Let $x \in U^\perp$. Then if $b\in B\subseteq U$, we have $Tx\perp b$
since $x \perp b$ (your assumption). Hence, $Tx \perp B$ and by linearity and continuity $Tx \perp U$. Thus, $Tx \in U^\perp$. Since $x \in U^\perp$ was arbitrary, we can conclude.

From (5), you can also immediately see your result. Indeed, note that $U^\perp \subseteq B^\perp$ (in fact this is even equality) and thus $TU^\perp \subseteq TB^\perp$. Hence, by $(5)$ we have $TU^\perp \perp U$ and thus $TU^\perp \subseteq U^\perp.$